why my SwiftData Query freeze the ui , how to solve?
I wrote a simple Home view that uses a LazyVGrid to display all my playlists. The playlists are queried using SwiftData‘s @Query, but I have no idea why the UI freezes. There is only one playlist in the database, so it can’t be due to too much data.
I'm using the query in the right way?
my home view is the following:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

enum stateMode  {
    case deleteMode
    case updateMode
    case normalMode
}

struct Home: View {
    @State private var mode: stateMode = .normalMode
    var columns: [GridItem] {
        return [
            GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 10, alignment: .center),
            GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 10, alignment: .center),
            GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 10, alignment: .center)
        ]
    }
    @Query var playList : [PlayListModel] = []
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            
            
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(playList) { playlist in
                        Button {
                            
                        } label: {
                            PlaylistItemView(/*playlist: playlist,*/ mode: mode)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup {
                    Menu {
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                mode = .deleteMode
                            }
                        }) {
                            Label("Delete Mode", systemImage: "trash.circle.fill")
                        }
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                mode = .updateMode
                            }
                        }) {
                            Label("Update Mode", systemImage: "arrow.clockwise.circle.fill")
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PlaylistItemView: View {
    let mode: stateMode

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if mode == .normalMode {
                Image(systemName: "tv")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .padding()
            } else if mode == .deleteMode {
                Image(systemName: "trash.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .padding()
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .padding()
            }

            Text("TEST")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.2))
        .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}

// the data mode:

import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
final class PlayListModel {
    var id = UUID()
    var timestamp: Date
    var playlistName: String
    var playlistUrl: String
    var lastUpdate: Date
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \PlaylistGroup.playlistModel)
    var groups: [PlaylistGroup]
    
    init(timestamp: Date, playlistName: String, playlistUrl: String, lastUpdate: Date) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.playlistName = playlistName
        self.playlistUrl = playlistUrl
        self.lastUpdate = lastUpdate
        self.groups = []
    }
}

@Model
class PlaylistGroup: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var groupName: String
    var playlistModel: PlayListModel
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \PlaylistItem.group)
    var playlistItems: [PlaylistItem]
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), groupName: String, playlistModel: PlayListModel) {
        self.id = id
        self.groupName = groupName
        self.playlistModel = playlistModel
        self.playlistItems = []
    }
    
    // Required for Hashable conformance
    static func == (lhs: PlaylistGroup, rhs: PlaylistGroup) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}

@Model
class PlaylistItem: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var duration: Int?
    var tvgId: String?
    var tvgName: String?
    var tvgCountry: String?
    var tvgLanguage: String?
    var tvgLogo: String?
    var tvgChno: String?
    var tvgShift: String?
    var groupTitle: String
    var seasonNumber: Int?
    var episodeNumber: Int?
    var kind: String?
    var url: URL?
    var lastPlay: Date
    
    var group: PlaylistGroup?
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), duration: Int? = nil, tvgId: String? = nil, tvgName: String? = nil, tvgCountry: String? = nil, tvgLanguage: String? = nil, tvgLogo: String? = nil, tvgChno: String? = nil, tvgShift: String? = nil, groupTitle: String, seasonNumber: Int? = nil, episodeNumber: Int? = nil, kind: String? = nil, url: URL? = nil, lastPlay: Date) {
        self.id = id
        self.duration = duration
        self.tvgId = tvgId
        self.tvgName = tvgName
        self.tvgCountry = tvgCountry
        self.tvgLanguage = tvgLanguage
        self.tvgLogo = tvgLogo
        self.tvgChno = tvgChno
        self.tvgShift = tvgShift
        self.groupTitle = groupTitle
        self.seasonNumber = seasonNumber
        self.episodeNumber = episodeNumber
        self.kind = kind
        self.url = url
        self.lastPlay = lastPlay
    }
    
    // Required for Hashable conformance
    static func == (lhs: PlaylistItem, rhs: PlaylistItem) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}


Have you tried using @Query var playList: [PlayListModel]. Note, there is no need for Identifiable with var id, @Model already includes this.

nope I tried , but still same issue.

looks like the issue is inside the PalylistItemView, but I have no idea what. I don't see anything wrong

In your PlaylistItemView you could try
@Binding var mode: stateMode and call it like
PlaylistItemView(mode: $mode)

try it but unsuccessful

Solution: created a computed var imageName to get image name based on mode and removed if else from body
Cause: Unknown
struct PlaylistItemView: View {
    let mode: stateMode
    
    var imageName: String {
        switch mode {
        case .deleteMode:
            return "trash.circle.fill"
        case .normalMode:
            return "tv"
        default:
            return "arrow.clockwise.circle.fill"
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: imageName)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .padding()
            Text("TEST")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.2))
        .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}

